# Static lookup data stored in localhost for 1000+ users (connections)

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes you have static data that is used by all customers. I am looking for a solution that fetches this from localhost (127.0.0.1) using a sort of database.

I have done some tests using Golang fetching from a local Postgresql database and it works perfect. But how does this scale to 1000+ users?

I noticed that only 1 session was started at the local server regardless which computer (as I used 127.0.0.1 in Golang to call Postgres). At some point this may or maybe not be a bottleneck for 1000 users to only using one session?

My questions are:

1. How many concurrent users can Postgresql handle per session before
   it become a bottleneck? Or is this handled by the calling language (Golang)?
2. Is it even possible to handle many queries per session from
   different users?
3. Is there other better ways to manage static lookup data for all customers than a local Postgresql database (Redis?)

I hope this question fits this forum. Otherwise, please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Every session creates a new postgres process, which gets forked from the "main" postgres process listening to the port (default 5432).

Default is that 100 sessions can be opened in parallel, but this can easily be changed in postgresql.conf.

There are no parallel queries being executed in one session.

Comment: The last sentence is wrong: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html

Comment: Strange. I have 2 computers and executed same REST query and got the same session and same PID for both queries. How do I ensure that a new session is started using localhost?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's not parallel queries that is possible, it's just parallelized single query. You cannot start another query before the current one is finished.